# Ho can i change the array structre?

Tags: php, arrays, structure

I get the following array structure from the database and can not get further here. Maybe someone can help me to change the array structure.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 302
        [name] => Test Name
    )
)
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 342
        [name] => Test Name 2
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 346
        [name] => Test Name 3
    )
)
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 344
        [name] => Test Name 4
    )
)
```

I need an array structure according to the following logic:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 302
        [name] => Test Name
    )
)
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 342
        [name] => Test Name 2
    )
)
Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 346
        [name] => Test Name 3
    )
)
Array
(
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 344
        [name] => Test Name 4
    )
)
```

The following PHP code generates the output

$resultUpdateInstition – that's the Database Array

```
        $output = false;
        if (is_array($resultUpdateInstition)) {
        foreach ($resultUpdateInstition as $keyUpdateInstition1 => $valueUpdateInstition1) {

            if (is_array($valueUpdateInstition1)) {
            $v = 0;
            foreach ($valueUpdateInstition1 as $keyUpdateInstition1 => $valueUpdateInstition1) {

                if (is_array($valueUpdateInstition1)) {
                foreach ($valueUpdateInstition1 as $usrvalvalvalkey => $usrvalvalvalval) {
                    $output .= $usrvalvalvalkey . " => " . $usrvalvalvalval . '<br />';
                }
                } else {
                 $output = $keyUpdateInstition1 . " => " . $valueUpdateInstition1 ;

                }
            }
            } else {
            $output = $valueUpdateInstition1;
            }
        }
        }

        print_r($output);
```

I hope someone know what i mean…, that will be great.
Many thx for your help

m.orange

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_merge to combine all of the arrays into one. Here is an example to get you going.

```
<?php

$arr1 = Array
(
    0 => Array
    (
        'id' => 302,
        'name' => 'Test Name',
    )
);
$arr2 = Array
(
    0 => Array
    (
        'id' => 342,
        'name' => 'Test Name 2',
    ),
    1 => Array
    (
        'id' => 346,
        'name' => 'Test Name 3',
    )
);
$arr3 = Array
(
    0 => Array
    (
        'id' => 344,
        'name' => 'Test Name 4',
    )
);

$arr4 = array_merge( $arr1, $arr2, $arr3 );

var_dump( $arr4 );

/*
result:
array(4) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(302) ["name"]=> string(9) "Test Name" } 
    [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(342) ["name"]=> string(11) "Test Name 2" } 
    [2]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(346) ["name"]=> string(11) "Test Name 3" } 
    [3]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(344) ["name"]=> string(11) "Test Name 4" } 
}
*/
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b627ec59b07f8ad6a15c9b25125b0bf15ced7e67

Comment: Hmm, somehow this does not work with my construct, I'm already iterating in 2 foreach grind. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You are concatenating strings to create your array?!?!! You need better variable names too.  $usrvalvalvalval is just monstrous. Don't split the arrays and recombine them as a long string, just merge your arrays.

Comment: Thx for your help guys. I had to restructure the code, now it works. :)